# How to make grep ignore windows line breaks?

Tags: windows, bash, grep, line-endings

On Mac OS X I have a file with windows line breaks and the following content

```
$ file file_windows.txt 
file_windows.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ cat file_windows.txt
IgnoreMe
FindMe
```

Strangely when I use grep to match "FindMe" and combine the result with another variable the result of grep is ignored:

```
$ echo $(grep "FindMe" file_windows.txt)$SHELL
/bin/bash
```

When I convert my file to use unix line endings

```
tr -d '\r' < file_windows.txt > file_unix.txt
```

then suddenly my grep command combined with another variable works

```
$ echo $(grep "FindMe" file_unix.txt)$SHELL
FindMe/bin/bash
```

How can I make grep ignore the (windows) line breaks, so that followings commands combining the outcome of grep with another variable always works as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run:

```
$ echo $(grep "FindMe" file_windows.txt)$SHELL
```

echo will print the line containing FindMe which, in turn, contains a \r character so that $SHELL will **overwrite** FindMe\r. You can easily check this by redirecting echo to file.

To fix this problem you can ask grep to terminate matching string with a "zero byte", this way:

```
$ echo $(grep -Z "FindMe" file_windows.txt)$SHELL
```

**EDIT**

I did notice you're using OSX. In this case use the following:

```
$ echo $(grep -o "FindMe" file_windows.txt)$SHELL
```

to print only "matching string"

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tr -d $'\r' < file_windows.txt > file_unix.txt
```

or

```
sed -e 's/\r$//' file_windows.txt > file_unix.txt
```

or since you're on OsX you could install `dos2unix`

Regards

Claudio

Comment: I know this command. But what I want to achieve is that the output of grep is the same for files with windows line endings and unix file endings (without the need to convert all the files beforehand).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
echo "$(tr -d '\r' < file_windows.txt | grep FindMe)$SHELL"
```

I start with putting double quotes around the echo parameters. That looks better.
With other commands where you cannot replace reading from a file by reading from a command, you can use another command

```
echo "$(grep "FindMe" <(tr -d '\r' < file_windows.txt))$SHELL"
```

What is happening here?
I start with putting double quotes around the echo parameters. That looks better.
You already found the tr command reading from stdin:

```
tr -d '\r' < file_windows.txt
```

With process substitution you can meke the output of some process look like a file for another process.
You can tell grep to read from the "file" `tr -d '\r' < file_windows.txt` using

```
grep "FindMe" <(tr -d '\r' < file_windows.txt)
```

Putting them together gives the command.

```
echo "$(grep "FindMe" <(tr -d '\r' < file_windows.txt))$SHELL"
```